# python change for_loop in list comprehesion

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've got the code as follows:

```
ix=0
list_test=[]
for el in parse_data_2['var_nm_final']:    
    if el=='URI':
        ix+=1
        list_test.append(ix)
    else:
        list_test.append(None)
```

parse_data_2 is my DF. As an output I would like to receive list with incremented value of ix or None depending on my condition. Meaning something like this

```
1
None
None
None
None
2
None
3
None
None
None
None
4
```

... etc.

I've tried to convert this loop to list comprehesion like this:

```
[ix+=1 if el=='URI'else None for el in parse_data_2['var_nm_final']]
```

but got error

```
[ix+=1 if el=='URI'else None for el in parse_data_2['var_nm_final']]
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you explain me the issue with my code?

Comment: Personally I would use the explicit loop in this case.  It's clear what it does, it's extremely easy to read, and it does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `next` on an `itertools.count` (or just `range` with generous upper bound):

```
>>> parse_data_2 = {'var_nm_final': ["URI", "foo", "bar", "URI", "URI", "blub", "URI"]}
>>> import itertools
>>> cnt = itertools.count(1)
>>> [next(cnt) if el == "URI" else None for el in parse_data_2["var_nm_final"]]
[1, None, None, 2, 3, None, 4]
```

Comment: Awsome, didn't know it. thx

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use-case for [the walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/)!
But please, don't do this. Whatever you're trying to accomplish, this can almost certainly be done in a pythonic *and* performant manner.

```py
[(ix:=ix+1) if el=='URI'else None for el in parse_data_2['var_nm_final']]
```

Comment: well.. it's a usecase, I grant that ;)

Comment: Please never write code like this...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I hear you, this is terrible code. That said, it does what OP asked for...

Comment: What are disadvantages of this code?

Comment: @data_b77 whatever you're trying to do with your `el` variable can likely be accomplished by something like `parse_data_2['var_nm_final'].eq('URI').sum()` or similar -- generating a list comprehension *with side-effects on your element generator* is poor form, and likely not the most performant solution either.